# Multiple authors in multiple lines in rmarkdown beamer presentations

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to breakdown the authors' names into two lines in Rmarkdown beamer presentation. My YAML is as follows:

```
---
title: "***"
author:
- Author One
- Author Two
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
fontsize: 14pt
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    fig_height: 5
    fig_width: 8
    highlight: tango
    theme: metropolis
incremental: true
---
```

But still, the authors' names printed on the same line. How can I break into two?

Answer (score 5):

If you use the `TeX` command `\newline` after the first author this will render on a second line.

```
---
title: "***"
author:
- Author One\newline
- Author Two
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B %Y')`"
fontsize: 14pt
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    fig_height: 5
    fig_width: 8
    highlight: tango
    theme: metropolis
incremental: true
---
```

Comment: @user7892705, no worries. Please mark as the accepted answer if that meets your expectation.